# How facebook realtime updates work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been researching the Facebook realtime updates for some time now and I still don't really understand how it works. How do I specify what user I want to receive updates for? The application that I am creating doesn't contain the log in process. It receives the access token for a user from another application. Is there a way for me to use the user's access token to then sign up for updates for that user?

Also, when Facebook sends me the POST containing the updated fields, how can I tell what user was updated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set up the Realtime API for one specific App by publishing to the subscriptions connection with an App Access Token of that App: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/app/subscriptions

After subscribing to a specific field, you will get a POST request to the callback whenever data of a **User who authorized that App** changes. You never need any User Token, and the POST request should contain the App Scoped User ID that is unique only in that specific App.

Comment: So I don't have it do it per user? It automatically will send the updates for any user that has authorized my app? @luschn

Comment: yes, that´s how it should work, but you can´t use the user token from another app, of course. as it states in the docs: "Subscriptions for the object type user will only be valid for users who have installed the app."

Comment: pages are different though, you must install an app on a page in order to get realtime callbacks for that page. since pages can´t really authorize apps, it makes sense.

Comment: Well the applications are running on the server separately but they use the same facebook account so I think I'm good. Thanks! @luschn